# css flexbox special 2 column layout

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

i'm playing around with flexbox and want to create a layout with two columns.

[image]

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="1" class="h">1</div>
  <div id="2" class="c">2</div>
  <div id="3" class="h">3</div>
  <div id="3" class="c">4</div>
  <div id="4" class="h">5</div>
  <div id="5" class="c">6</div>
</div>
```

Is it somehow possible to align the items like in the screenshot?

[> link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee7AA.png)

Comment: With flexbox *naturally*? No...you could force it but you could force any layout.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your screenshot but it seems to me like your css shold be something like this:

```
.h{
    float:left;
}
.c{
    float:right;
}
.h, .c{
    width:45%;
    padding:2.5%;
}
```

Comment: there is a link at the bottom of my article to the screenshot
i already tried it with floating, but that approach doesn't work

Comment: just saw your screenshot and yes, this css should work for you

Answer (score 0):

[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/zooxstudio/sLq0c7aj/) to check the fiddle of my version of it

```css
.h, .c{
  background:#ccc;
  width:100%;
  min-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}

.c{
  background:#666;
  }
  
  .wrapper{
    min-width:50%;
  }
  
  

.wrapper-main{
  display:flex;
    flex-direction:row; 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-main">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="1" class="h">1</div>
  <div id="3" class="h">3</div>
  <div id="4" class="h">5</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="2" class="c">2</div>
  <div id="3" class="c">4</div>
    <div id="5" class="c">6</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't start `id` [with a number](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/). Next, you're better off with floats with this one.

```
.wrapper > div {
  width: 50%; 
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left; 
  clear: left; 
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(even) {
  float: right; 
  clear: right;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/remQXJ).